# java read properties and xml file using stringbuilder

Tags: java

I need to read a set of xml and property files and parse the data. Currently I am using inputstream ans string builder to do this. But this does not create the file in the same way as input file is. I donot want to remove the white spaces and new lines. How do i achieve this.

```
is = test.getInputStream();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line5;
StringBuilder sb5 = new StringBuilder();
while ((line5 = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb5.append(line5);
} 
String s = sb5.toString();
```

**My output is:**

`#test 123 #test2 345`

**Expected output is:**

```
#test
123
#test2
345
```

Any thoughts ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

br.readLine() consumes the line breaks, you need to add them to your StringBuilder after appending the line.

```
is = test.getInputStream();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line5;
StringBuilder sb5 = new StringBuilder();
while ((line5 = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb5.append(line5);
    sb5.append("\n");
}
```

If you want an extremely simple solution for reading a file to a String, [Apache Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) has a method for performing such a task ([org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)).

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(File file, String encoding);
```

Answer (score 1):

`readLine()` method doesn't add the EOL character (\n). So while appending the string to the builder, you need to add the EOL char, like `sb5.append(line5+"\n");`

Answer (score 1):

The various `readLine` methods discard the newline from the input.

From the [`BufferedReader` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

A solution may be as simple as adding back a newline to your `StringBuilder` for every `readLine`: `sb5.append(line5 + "\n");`.

A better alternative is to read into an intermediate buffer first, using the `read` method, supplying your own `char[]`. You can still use [`StringBuilder.append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%5b%5d%29), and get a String will match the file contents.